# ffmpeg audio sync issue when using hstack filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two .webm videos which I'm trying to process into a horizontally stacked single video with one video on the left and one video on the right.

The individual video files are called left.webm and right.webm. They both have perfect audio/video sync when I play them. I'm using the following command to do the hstack:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i left.webm -i right.webm -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[left];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[right];[left][right]hstack=inputs=2[v];[a:0][1:a]amerge[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 merged.webm -loglevel error
```

The command works fine, but I have a synchronisation issue between the audio and the video on the merged result.

Reading through some SE posts (audio sync appears to be quite a common issue) lead me to using ffprobe to try and understand the parameters of each of the left and right videos and to look for anomalies like frame rate differences.

ffprobe produces this for left.webm:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 320x240, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 1k fps, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
```

And right.webm:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 320x240, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
```

I noticed that left.webm has an fps of 1k, so I tried transcoding that down to 30fps to match right.webm with:

```
ffmpeg -i left.webm -r 30 -vcodec copy left2.webm
```

But I still have the audio synchronisation (it's about 200-300ms off, at my best guess) in the resulting merged video when I do the hstack filter.

I'm not sure what to check next given both videos appear to have identical parameters and play perfectly individually.

Any thoughts on what to look at or try next would be gratefully received!

Thanks.

```
ffprobe -show_entries packet=pts_time -select_streams v -read_intervals %5 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0 left.webm
0.438000
0.439000
0.439000
0.459000
0.487000
0.516000
0.547000
0.579000
0.610000
0.642000
0.675000
0.708000
0.742000
0.774000
0.807000
0.840000
0.873000
0.906000
0.907000
0.940000
0.973000
1.006000
1.039000
1.072000
1.105000
1.139000
1.205000
1.272000
1.338000
1.339000
1.405000
1.471000
1.538000
1.604000
1.671000
1.738000
1.804000
1.871000
1.872000
1.904000
1.937000
1.971000
2.004000
2.037000
2.071000
2.104000
2.137000
2.138000
2.170000
2.204000
2.237000
2.270000
2.304000
2.337000
2.370000
2.404000
2.437000
2.470000
2.471000
2.504000
2.537000
2.570000
2.604000
2.637000
2.670000
2.704000
2.737000
2.770000
2.803000
2.804000
2.837000
2.870000
2.903000
2.937000
2.970000
3.003000
3.037000
3.070000
3.103000
3.137000
3.138000
3.170000
3.203000
3.237000
3.270000
3.303000
3.337000
3.370000
3.403000
3.437000
3.470000
3.471000
3.503000
3.537000
3.570000
3.603000
3.636000
3.670000
3.703000
3.736000
3.770000
3.803000
3.804000
3.836000
3.870000
3.903000
3.936000
3.970000
4.003000
4.036000
4.070000
4.103000
4.136000
4.137000
4.170000
4.203000
4.236000
4.270000
4.303000
4.336000
4.369000
4.403000
4.436000
4.469000
4.470000
4.503000
4.536000
4.569000
4.603000
4.636000
4.669000
4.703000
4.736000
4.769000
4.803000
4.804000
4.836000
4.869000
4.902000
4.936000
4.969000
```

---

```
ffprobe -show_entries packet=pts_time -select_streams v -read_intervals %5 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0 right.webm
0.007000
0.040000
0.040000
0.074000
0.107000
0.140000
0.174000
0.207000
0.240000
0.274000
0.307000
0.340000
0.373000
0.374000
0.407000
0.440000
0.474000
0.507000
0.540000
0.574000
0.607000
0.640000
0.674000
0.707000
0.707000
0.740000
0.774000
0.807000
0.840000
0.874000
0.907000
0.940000
0.974000
1.007000
1.040000
1.040000
1.074000
1.107000
1.140000
1.174000
1.207000
1.240000
1.274000
1.307000
1.340000
1.373000
1.374000
1.407000
1.440000
1.474000
1.507000
1.540000
1.574000
1.607000
1.640000
1.674000
1.707000
1.707000
1.740000
1.774000
1.807000
1.840000
1.874000
1.907000
1.940000
1.974000
2.007000
2.040000
2.040000
2.074000
2.107000
2.140000
2.174000
2.207000
2.240000
2.274000
2.307000
2.340000
2.373000
2.374000
2.407000
2.440000
2.474000
2.507000
2.540000
2.574000
2.607000
2.640000
2.674000
2.707000
2.707000
2.740000
2.774000
2.807000
2.840000
2.874000
2.907000
2.940000
2.974000
3.007000
3.040000
3.040000
3.074000
3.107000
3.140000
3.174000
3.207000
3.240000
3.274000
3.307000
3.340000
3.373000
3.374000
3.407000
3.440000
3.474000
3.507000
3.540000
3.574000
3.607000
3.640000
3.674000
3.707000
3.707000
3.740000
3.774000
3.807000
3.840000
3.874000
3.907000
3.940000
3.974000
4.007000
4.040000
4.040000
4.074000
4.107000
4.140000
4.174000
4.207000
4.240000
4.274000
4.307000
4.340000
4.373000
4.374000
4.407000
4.440000
4.474000
4.507000
4.540000
4.574000
4.607000
4.640000
4.674000
4.707000
4.707000
4.740000
4.774000
4.807000
4.840000
4.874000
4.907000
4.940000
4.974000
```

---

```
ffprobe -show_entries packet=pts_time -select_streams a -read_intervals %5 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0 left.webm
-0.007000
0.014000
0.034000
0.054000
0.074000
0.094000
0.114000
0.134000
0.154000
0.174000
0.194000
0.214000
0.234000
0.254000
0.274000
0.294000
0.314000
0.334000
0.354000
0.374000
0.394000
0.414000
0.434000
0.454000
0.474000
0.494000
0.514000
0.534000
0.554000
0.574000
0.594000
0.614000
0.634000
0.654000
0.674000
0.694000
0.714000
0.734000
0.754000
0.774000
0.794000
0.814000
0.834000
0.854000
0.874000
0.894000
0.914000
0.934000
0.954000
0.974000
0.994000
1.014000
1.034000
1.054000
1.074000
1.094000
1.114000
1.134000
1.154000
1.174000
1.194000
1.214000
1.234000
1.254000
1.274000
1.294000
1.314000
1.334000
1.354000
1.374000
1.394000
1.414000
1.434000
1.454000
1.474000
1.494000
1.514000
1.534000
1.554000
1.574000
1.594000
1.614000
1.634000
1.654000
1.674000
1.694000
1.714000
1.734000
1.754000
1.774000
1.794000
1.814000
1.834000
1.854000
1.874000
1.894000
1.914000
1.934000
1.954000
1.974000
1.994000
2.014000
2.034000
2.054000
2.074000
2.094000
2.114000
2.134000
2.154000
2.174000
2.194000
2.214000
2.234000
2.254000
2.274000
2.294000
2.314000
2.334000
2.354000
2.374000
2.394000
2.414000
2.434000
2.454000
2.474000
2.494000
2.514000
2.534000
2.554000
2.574000
2.594000
2.614000
2.634000
2.654000
2.674000
2.694000
2.714000
2.734000
2.754000
2.774000
2.794000
2.814000
2.834000
2.854000
2.874000
2.894000
2.914000
2.934000
2.954000
2.974000
2.994000
3.014000
3.034000
3.054000
3.074000
3.094000
3.114000
3.134000
3.154000
3.174000
3.194000
3.214000
3.234000
3.254000
3.274000
3.294000
3.314000
3.334000
3.354000
3.374000
3.394000
3.414000
3.434000
3.454000
3.474000
3.494000
3.514000
3.534000
3.554000
3.574000
3.594000
3.614000
3.634000
3.654000
3.674000
3.694000
3.714000
3.734000
3.754000
3.774000
3.794000
3.814000
3.834000
3.854000
3.874000
3.894000
3.914000
3.934000
3.954000
3.974000
3.994000
4.014000
4.034000
4.054000
4.074000
4.094000
4.114000
4.134000
4.154000
4.174000
4.194000
4.214000
4.234000
4.254000
4.274000
4.294000
4.314000
4.334000
4.354000
4.374000
4.394000
4.414000
4.434000
4.454000
4.474000
4.494000
4.514000
4.534000
4.554000
4.574000
4.594000
4.614000
4.634000
4.654000
4.674000
4.694000
4.714000
4.734000
4.754000
4.774000
4.794000
4.814000
4.834000
4.854000
4.874000
4.894000
4.914000
4.934000
4.954000
4.974000
4.994000
```

---

```
ffprobe -show_entries packet=pts_time -select_streams a -read_intervals %5 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0 right.webm
-0.007000
0.014000
0.034000
0.054000
0.074000
0.094000
0.114000
0.134000
0.154000
0.174000
0.194000
0.214000
0.234000
0.254000
0.274000
0.294000
0.314000
0.334000
0.354000
0.374000
0.394000
0.414000
0.434000
0.454000
0.474000
0.494000
0.514000
0.534000
0.554000
0.574000
0.594000
0.614000
0.634000
0.654000
0.674000
0.694000
0.714000
0.734000
0.754000
0.774000
0.794000
0.814000
0.834000
0.854000
0.874000
0.894000
0.914000
0.934000
0.954000
0.974000
0.994000
1.014000
1.034000
1.054000
1.074000
1.094000
1.114000
1.134000
1.154000
1.174000
1.194000
1.214000
1.234000
1.254000
1.274000
1.294000
1.314000
1.334000
1.354000
1.374000
1.394000
1.414000
1.434000
1.454000
1.474000
1.494000
1.514000
1.534000
1.554000
1.574000
1.594000
1.614000
1.634000
1.654000
1.674000
1.694000
1.714000
1.734000
1.754000
1.774000
1.794000
1.814000
1.834000
1.854000
1.874000
1.894000
1.914000
1.934000
1.954000
1.974000
1.994000
2.014000
2.034000
2.054000
2.074000
2.094000
2.114000
2.134000
2.154000
2.174000
2.194000
2.214000
2.234000
2.254000
2.274000
2.294000
2.314000
2.334000
2.354000
2.374000
2.394000
2.414000
2.434000
2.454000
2.474000
2.494000
2.514000
2.534000
2.554000
2.574000
2.594000
2.614000
2.634000
2.654000
2.674000
2.694000
2.714000
2.734000
2.754000
2.774000
2.794000
2.814000
2.834000
2.854000
2.874000
2.894000
2.914000
2.934000
2.954000
2.974000
2.994000
3.014000
3.034000
3.054000
3.074000
3.094000
3.114000
3.134000
3.154000
3.174000
3.194000
3.214000
3.234000
3.254000
3.274000
3.294000
3.314000
3.334000
3.354000
3.374000
3.394000
3.414000
3.434000
3.454000
3.474000
3.494000
3.514000
3.534000
3.554000
3.574000
3.594000
3.614000
3.634000
3.654000
3.674000
3.694000
3.714000
3.734000
3.754000
3.774000
3.794000
3.814000
3.834000
3.854000
3.874000
3.894000
3.914000
3.934000
3.954000
3.974000
3.994000
4.014000
4.034000
4.054000
4.074000
4.094000
4.114000
4.134000
4.154000
4.174000
4.194000
4.214000
4.234000
4.254000
4.274000
4.294000
4.314000
4.334000
4.354000
4.374000
4.394000
4.414000
4.434000
4.454000
4.474000
4.494000
4.514000
4.534000
4.554000
4.574000
4.594000
4.614000
4.634000
4.654000
4.674000
4.694000
4.714000
4.734000
4.754000
4.774000
4.794000
4.814000
4.834000
4.854000
4.874000
4.894000
4.914000
4.934000
4.954000
4.974000
4.994000
```

Comment: Can you share the files?

Comment: Hi Mulvya - that would be tricky as it's two people talking in a video conference (confidentiality etc). I can see if I can produce a couple of test videos to use.

Is there something in particular you would look at in the two videos that I could look at and report on?

Comment: The timestamps for the audio and video in both the files. Run and capture output of `ffprobe -show_entries packet=pts_time -select_streams v -read_intervals %5 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0 file.webm`. Run same command with `v` changed to `a`. Do this for both files.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. Output is <too long for SE - will past up somewhere else and link>

Comment: I have edited the main post and added the output there. Thanks Mulvya.

Comment: The left video has a late starting video but not audio, so first try is to skip the setpts filters for both videos.

Comment: And bingo. Now everything is in sync.

I am batch processing these. Should I generally skip the setpts filter or is it a good idea in certain circumstances ?

Comment: If A and V don't start at same time, and if V is significantly delayed then that video will have a frozen first frame till its start PTS is reached. Other than that, it should be fine.

Comment: Got it, so as part of any pre-processing I should check those start values and then act accordingly. Thanks for your help Mulvya (and for all your other help all over the internet - I've seen your name in countless threads that have helped me!).

Comment: I'm not sure how I confirm that as the answer @mulvya ?

Also, the input videos were produced by me from separate audio and video streams which I merged with an offset (to correct original lipsync in the individual videos) using:

/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -itsoffset 0.43064 -i video.webm -i audio.opus -c:v copy -c:a copy left.webm

Is there a way I can merge them and reset these timestamps so that they do not get offset in this way when I do the horizontal stack to combine them?

Comment: Apply a negative offset to the audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For files with differing start times of video and audio streams, the PTS values should not be changed else sync will be lost.

So,

```
ffmpeg -y -i left.webm -i right.webm -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[v];[a:0][1:a]amerge[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 merged.webm
```